# Как вернуть результаты в любом случае если нет связи в join и убрать все что не совпадают?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, запрос, join

Очень большая проблема которую не могу решить несколько дней.

У меня есть таблица `table2` которая связана с `table1`. И у каждого пользователя есть свой `id`, в таблице `table2` может быть только одна запись для определенного `t1id` с `userid`.

Вот запросы для наглядности:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(100));
CREATE TABLE table2 (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, t1id INT, userid INT, state BOOLEAN);
INSERT INTO table1 (name) VALUES ('Mike'), ('Brad'), ('Ivan'), ('ktoto');
INSERT INTO table2 (t1id, userid, state) VALUES (1, 1, TRUE), (2, 1, FALSE), (4, 1, FALSE);
SELECT t1.name FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.t1id AND t2.userid = 1 AND t2.state = TRUE;
```

Мне нужен такой запрос который выдаст строки из `table1` даже если в таблице `table2` нету строк совпадающих по условию после `ON`. `LEFT JOIN` это делает. И одновременно с этим, если нашлась таблица в `table2` связанная с `table1` и последующие условия ложные, то убрать такую строку из запроса. `LEFT JOIN` вообще плевать, что те условия ложные как видите.

Выводится:

```
+-------+
| name  |
+-------+
| Mike  |
| Brad  |
| Ivan  |
| ktoto |
+-------+
```

Требуемый результат:

```
+-------+
| name  |
+-------+
| Mike  |
| Ivan  |
+-------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По-моему, требуется

```sql
SELECT t1.name 
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.t1id
WHERE (t2.t1id IS NULL)
   OR (t2.userid, t2.state) = (1, TRUE);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bbf38f4dca30a7bbccf6d2a932985e83)

Comment: Спасибо разобрался!